# Facebook Graph API - get all user's liked pages

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I would like to retrieve **all** facebook pages liked by a certain user.
The problem is that a /user/likes endpoint returns the list in parts (pagination).
Is there an option to display them all in one page? Facebook docs do not provide such info.

P.S. pagination does not seem to return all the pages. Some of them are missing.

10x.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get all pages in one call, you have to use pagination. If pages are missing, you should file a bug.

Btw, you can also try setting a limit:

```
me/likes?limit=100
```

...but there is a max value for that, so you can never be sure to get all pages in one call without paging.